# ractive warning "Two-way binding does not work with expressions"

Tags: ractivejs

This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rn6qwn92/1/),when I click the checkbox "chooseAll",There is a warning in console,that say

`` Two-way binding does not work with expressions (`items.length===hasChooedItems().length` on <input> ``,
 I change the ractive's version form "latest" to "0.6.1",when i click the "chooseAll",there is a wrong in console,that say`Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`. why?

Answer (score 4):

The warning you get with the latest version is essentially protecting you from the error you see with 0.6.1.

Two-way binding only works with simple references (like `<input type='checkbox' value='{{foo}}'>`), because Ractive knows how to update its model when you interact with that checkbox, by toggling the value of `foo` - more complex expressions can't use two-way binding (if `value='{{a || b}}'`, there's no way to determine whether it's `a` or `b` that should toggle, for example). So in those cases we have to listen for `change` events and handle them ourselves (hence `on-change='toggleAll'`).

Older versions of Ractive would fail to recognise the problem and try to update the binding, causing that internal error. Now, you get the warning up-front.

You can either ignore it - it's harmless - or eliminate the warning by specifying `twoway='false'` on the input. That's equivalent to saying 'it's okay, Ractive, I got this'. Here's a [fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/dnzzr5ab/) with that change on line 17.